# SQLite Android While adding new customer in database nothing happens

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a problem like this:

I have registration form for new customer but then he filled out all fields like login, password and so on. Nothing happened in Base SQL.

I don`t understand my mistake here.

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.create_account:

        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        contentValues = new ContentValues();

        // AlertDialog Registration
        View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.registration_form, (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content), false);
        inputPassword = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        inputLogin = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.input_login);
        inputEmail = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.input_email);

        builder.setView(viewInflated);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String login = inputLogin.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                // Передаем с помошью КонтентВелью наши значения из полей
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_NAME, login);
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_EMAIL, email);
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

                // Записываем в базу ТейблКонтакты
                database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);

                database.close();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы зарегистрированы", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               toast.show();
               dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
```

And my DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactDb";
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_PASSWORD + " text" + KEY_EMAIL + " text" + ")");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

Comment: You need a comma, after `text`. Here `KEY_PASSWORD + " text"+ KEY_EMAIL`

Comment: i fixed it, but not working

Comment: After changing `KEY_PASSWORD + "text" ....` to `KEY_PASSWORD + "text," ....` (i.e. added comma), did you delete the database or change the version? That is `onCreate` will only run when creating the database, `onUpgrade` will only run if the version is changed. If neither are run the database will not be changed. There are other ways but would require additional coding (personally I'd delete the app's data when developing unless you have a lot of data.